# show product catalog in wordpress not for e-commerce

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to build a website that view product catalog but not for e-commerce. and product category is shown in sidebar [like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5qEn.png).  which plugin or custom thing should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You can have that with an e-commerce theme using woocommerce plugin, you will be able to add your products and specify their categories (categories can be displayed using a widget, most e-commerce themes have that). To transform the shop into a catalog (without cart functionality) add one of the following plugins :

- [Catalog Visibility Options](https://woocommerce.com/products/catalog-visibility-options/) that is a great one because it's made
  by Woocommerce team, it adds new options to Woocommerce settings. This plugin is a paid one.
- [YITH WooCommerce Catalog Mode](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-catalog-mode/)